# Angular js 1.4.8 Injection module error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement oauth service in angular 1.4.8. I am getting an error in console like this:

Uncaught Error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularoauthexample…udflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4458n @ angular.js:340g @ angular.js:4419eb @ angular.js:4344c @ angular.js:1676yc @ angular.js:1697Zd @ angular.js:1591(anonymous function) @ angular.js:29013j @ jquery.js:3148k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">        

        <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--font-awesome-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!--Bootstrap social-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-social.css">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>


    <body ng-app="angularoauthexampleApp">
        <div id="wrap">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand em-text" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-1x" style="color:whitesmoke"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><p class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</p></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                Login via
                                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                                    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()"><i class="fa fa-google" ng-click="login()"></i> Google</button>-->
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-google"><i class="fa fa-google" ng-click="login()"></i> Google</a>
                                                </div>
                                                or
                                                <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                                        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                                New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </nav>


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript + Angular Js
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Angular code:

App.js:

```
'use strict';

    angular
      .module('angularoauthexampleApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
      ])
      .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          })
          .when('/afterlogin', {
            templateUrl: 'views/afterlogin.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
          })
          .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
            template: '',
            controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
              var hash = $location.path().substr(1);

              var splitted = hash.split('&');
              var params = {};

              for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
                var key    = param[0];
                var value  = param[1];
                params[key] = value;
                $rootScope.accesstoken=params;
              }
              $location.path("/afterlogin");
            }
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      });
```

Main.js

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.login=function() {
        var client_id="343625411797-hcm0impil8l1mughb8ma2jj966um05bp.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        var scope="email";
        var redirect_uri="http://localhost:9046/RTH_Sample4/app/";
        var response_type="token";
        var url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope="+scope+"&client_id="+client_id+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+
        "&response_type="+response_type;
        window.location.replace(url);
    };
  });
```

About.js

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.root=$rootScope;
  });
```

I tried searching online for a fix but nothing worked so far.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Show us some code, specifically how you include the angularjs and oauth service, and how you are adding the service to the app

Comment: @AlexD Updated the question

Comment: If you re using the bootstrap angular module, please load bootstrap after the angular.min script

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error defining your controllers.

Instead of this:

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // controller content

});
```

try this instead:

```
angular.module('angularoauthexampleApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // controller content

}]);
```

See documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Good catch, In angluar 1.3 you can do both ways, angular 1.4 forces the new way.

Comment: I was missing a script tag for ng-route. Included the script tag fixed the error but the `login()` function is not working