# Angular 1.4.8 :angular module/ng-app error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written few very simple lines of code using angular 1.4.8 and I was getting

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'a' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Followed this link as I am also using the same version of angular.
[Angular js 1.4.8 Injection module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311730/angular-js-1-4-8-injection-module-error)

```
<div ng-app='a'>
<div ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name"/>
<input type="submit" ng-click="call();"/>
</div>
</div>
```

```
var a=angular.module('a',[]);
a.controller("myctrl",['$scope',function($scope){

var ctrl=this;

$scope.call=function(){
alert(ctrl.name);
};

}]);
```

here is link to my fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/rakotkar/mumv3uwf/4/

Comment: Getting help for JSFiddle issues on StackOverflow feels like a waste of time. JSFiddle is a sandbox, not somewhere to be developing code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I get error module not available in JSFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890420/why-i-get-error-module-not-available-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things,

(i) Angular reference is not getting loaded ,  you just need to change

**`Javascript settings -> Load type -> Wrap in <Head>`**

[image]

(ii)You need to change the controller code as,

```
var a=angular.module('a',[]);
a.controller("myctrl",function(){
var ctrl=this;
ctrl.call=function(){
alert(ctrl.name);
};
});
```

**[`WORKING FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/qe8LfLzv/)**

Comment: What OP has is a little messy but I see no reason to set `call` on the controller instance when OP already has it on `$scope`

Comment: @Phil The main issue is because of the reference which i have posted

Comment: @Sajeetharan: thaks for your help but following only first point fixed the issue for me. https://jsfiddle.net/rakotkar/mumv3uwf/5/

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar Good! but its always better to use controller as syntax

Answer (score 0):

- Just assign `$scope` to `ctrl` object instead of `this` key word like `var ctrl=$scope;`

**code :**

```
var a=angular.module('a',[]);
a.controller("myctrl",['$scope',function($scope){
var ctrl=$scope;
$scope.call=function(){
alert(ctrl.name);
};
}]);
```

---

- And you should define the angular reference inside the `head` tag

---

- Finally remove `ctrl` ( no need to use ) alias in `ng-controller` attribute

**code :**

```
<div ng-app='a'>
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
<input type="submit" ng-click="call();"/>
</div>
</div>
```

---

- [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mumv3uwf/7/)